# Creating folders using DriveApp.createFolder gives duplicates

Tags: google-app-maker

I am using a for loop to iterate over 105 records in a Pupils model in App Maker.
For each record in the model, I am extracting a folder name from a field in the model.

I am using the folder name as input to `DriveApp.createFolder()`.

Each folder is generated within the same root folder so that I end up with a root folder that has 105 newly created folders within it.

For each created folder, I assign ownership of the folder to a specific user and remove editing rights from the folder creator.

The root folder in this case has editing rights given to anyone in the domain with the link, so the created folder inherits this setting and this is why I remove the folder creator as an editor.

To help with my debugging, I write to the console after each folder is created and indicate which record from the pupil model is being processed.

What happens is that after about 25 to 30 folders have been created in the root folder the for loop seems to start again, but also continues from where it left off at the same time!

Here is a snippet from the debug console...

[[image: 1]]

You can see that the loop seems to start again.

Here is my code...

```
    function createEvidenceFolder(){
    var person = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
    var pupils = app.models.Pupils.newQuery();
    pupils.filters.EvidenceFolder._equals = null;
    pupils.filters.Roll._equals = "Current";
    var pupil = pupils.run();
    var folder = "XXXThe Root Folder IDXXX";
    for (var x = 0; x < pupil.length; x++){
    var fname = pupil[x].Folder_Name;    
  console.log("Processing record "+x+" for "+fname);    
 var root = DriveApp.getFolderById(folder);
 var createdfolder = root.createFolder(fname).getId();
 Utilities.sleep(1000);
 DriveApp.getFolderById(createdfolder).setOwner("The email address of the User").removeEditor(person);
  pupil[x].EvidenceFolder = createdfolder;   
  }
  app.saveRecords(pupil);   
  console.log("Processed "+x+" evidence folders");
}
```

I went back and added the `Utilities.sleep(1000)` as I was hunting for answers.

So why am I getting twice the number of folders that I should be?

Why does the for loop seem to run concurrently?

By the way, the script is triggered from an onclick event on a button.  The `onclick` event immediately hides the button `(widget.visible = false)` before calling the script with `google.script.run` so I am hopefully removing the chance to actually click twice!

I am at a loss to explain this, but I am also very new to App Maker and programing.

Does anybody have any insights?

Edit..  Misread the comment section after the reply from Morfinismo!

```
widget.visible = false;
google.script.run.withFailureHandler(function(err,user){
  console.log("The error was "+err+" and the user was "+user);}).createEvidenceFolder();
```

The above code is from the Button that handles triggering the server script.

Comment: From what I see, the server script is completely fine. The issue must be on the client side. Can you share how you are calling the server script form the client side? There is a chance the server script is triggered twice.

Comment: So the client side trigger is a Button with an onclick handler.  The script is 
widget.visible = false;
google.script.run.withFailureHandler(function(err,user){
  console.log("The error was "+err+" and the user was "+user);}).createEvidenceFolder();

I did run it without using a success or failure handler, but I noticed in the debug log that there was an error from the widget after some time had passed.  
I don't think I'm using the failure handler correctly though as the returns didn't yield anything useful.

Comment: Could you try the following: `console.log("Starting process");widget.enabled= false;
google.script.run.withFailureHandler(function(err){
  console.log("The error was "+err);}).withSuccessHandler(function(){widget.enabled=true; console.log("Finished process");}).createEvidenceFolder();`

Comment: I was going to go to bed, but had to try this before I went.  Morfinismo, your code was spot on!  No duplicates or concurrency with the widget disabled.
Is there a tendency in App Maker for buttons to fire another onclick?  Or is it just possible Google should introduce a delay to negate a debounce from a mouse click.
I think I'm going to use that method across all buttons in future.
Many thanks for your efforts in fixing this problem for me, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm concerned, there should be no issue whatsoever if you decide to hide the button instead of disabling it. Without inspecting the app, it's almost impossible to tell what might be wrong. My best guess is that somewhere in the app there is some code triggering that behavior or less likely, a bug within appmaker's system. I believe the latter is very unlikely because I tried a set up similar to yours and nothing went wrong.

Either or way, by trying to disable the widget instead of hiding might help:

```
console.log("Starting process");
widget.enabled= false; 
google.script.run.withFailureHandler(function(err){
    console.log("The error was "+err);}
).withSuccessHandler(function(){
    widget.enabled=true; 
    console.log("Finished process");
}).createEvidenceFolder();
```